# ReturnUrl is not formed properly while accessing one of my controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have one controller Jobs  when I'm trying to access this controller without logging to my portal, return url is not formed properly and it looks like
http://test-employer.cloudapp.net/accounts?ReturnUrl=%2F

and for accessing any other controller its formed properly
http://test-employer.cloudapp.net/accounts?ReturnUrl=%2Fusers
Below is my routing config

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "JobFeed",
    url: "jobs/{q}/jobfeed.xml",
    defaults: new { controller = "Jobs", action = "Feed", q = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "JobPostingFeed",
    url: "postings/{q}/jobfeed.xml",
    defaults: new { controller = "Postings", action = "Feed", q = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Why do you think its not property formed? `....accounts?ReturnUrl=%2F` means the return url is whatever you have defined as the default route (typically `/Home/Index`)

Comment: Hi @Stephen... i'm using default routing and it should return me http://test-employer.cloudapp.net/accounts?ReturnUrl=%2Fjobs, If I'm accessing jobs controller but same is not happening in my case

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "JobFeed",url: "jobs/{q}/jobfeed.xml",defaults: new { controller = "Jobs", action = "Feed", q = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "JobPostingFeed",
                url: "postings/{q}/jobfeed.xml",
                defaults: new { controller = "Postings", action = "Feed", q=UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

Comment: You need to add that to your question (to hard to decipher in comments). But it looks like your have the default route as `/Home/Index` so you will get `..?ReurnUrl=%2f`

Comment: I have added the routing config to my question ..but i just confused why jobs controller value is not append to return url if I access given url ...testemployer.cloudapp.net/jobs ..........while accessing any other controller directly its appended to return url value